# Declare own class in itself what mean?

Tags: java, android

Declare own class in itself what mean?

```
 public class SearchTaskResult {
    public final String txt;
    public final int   pageNumber;
    public final RectF searchBoxes[];
    static private SearchTaskResult singleton;

    SearchTaskResult(String _txt, int _pageNumber, RectF _searchBoxes[]) {
        txt = _txt;
        pageNumber = _pageNumber;
        searchBoxes = _searchBoxes;
    }

    static public SearchTaskResult get() {
        return singleton;
    }

    static public void set(SearchTaskResult r) {
        singleton = r;
    }
}
```

Declare this

```
static private SearchTaskResult singleton;
```

It return itself,I don't understand what does it mean

```
static public SearchTaskResult get() {
    return singleton;
}
```

I have read of singleton,

but this structure method don't have private modifier

```
SearchTaskResult(String _txt, int _pageNumber, RectF _searchBoxes[]) {
        txt = _txt;
        pageNumber = _pageNumber;
        searchBoxes = _searchBoxes;
    }
```

Comment: Look it up on google! its called just how the variable is named, singleton https://www.google.com/#fp=602390ab7130fb4f&q=what+is+singleton

Comment: Google [`singleton pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (_this code seems like a flawed example/implementation_)

Comment: [This](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) is pretty good reading, too...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about General conceptual question. Java concepts are not cleared of questioner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class implemeents singleton design pattern.
You can read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

*Sometimes it's important to have only **one instance** for a class. For example, in a system there should be only one window manager (or only a file system or only a print spooler). Usually singletons are used for centralized management of internal or external resources and they provide a global point of access to themselves.*

*The singleton pattern is one of the simplest design patterns: it involves only one class which is responsible to instantiate itself, to make sure it creates not more than one instance; in the same time it provides a global point of access to that instance. In this case the same instance can be used from everywhere, being impossible to invoke directly the constructor each time.*

[Singleton](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer... (_Oh wait, I already added it 20 minutes ago_)

Comment: oops didn't read it my bad :)